# Align link left of div

Tags: html, alignment, css

(I'll make this one like a riddle since my project is private at the moment ;) )

I have a navigation bar. It contains five links. Each one has a `padding: 1% ;`, `margin-right: 1%;` and are displayed `display: inline-block;`.

They are encased in a separate navigation div. What I am trying to do is align the text (Not the padding!) in the first link to the left side of the div.

i.e. The first link, but only the first link, aligns with the left of my containing div.

Thanks for any help in advance.

EDIT: Link to my page: www.lennardboehnke.com

Comment: Something like the css `:first-child` selector??

Comment: any code to share? if lot use `a:nth-child(1){margin-right:whatever;}`

Comment: I put a link to my site, not sure what you mean with the :first-child selector

Comment: For future reference, please include code and/or a JS Fiddle replicating the issue, that way if your site were to disappear or change the question would still have relevance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align the text of your first link to the left of the container (while retaining the padding for the hover effect) you can use the `first-child` pseudo selector to select the first `a` and apply a negative left `margin` equal to the amount of left `padding` to offset it.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
.content {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #818181;
    text-align: justify;
}
.nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 5% 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 1%;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 0 1%;
    transition: background 0.4s ease-in-out 0, color 0.4s ease-in-out 0;
}
.nav a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: cornflowerblue;
}
/*Negative margin applied here*/
.nav a:first-child {
    margin-left: -1%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="nav"> 
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="aboutme.php">About Me</a>
        <a href="blog.php">Blog</a>
        <a href="work.php">Work</a>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aobqzya0/